# R gsub and two spaces, and parentheses

Tags: r, regex, gsub

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("one space", "two  (spaces)"))
#>            col1
#> 1     one space
#> 2 two  (spaces)
```

When I try and replace the phrase `two  (spaces)` with `ts` I come up short:

```
# Try #1
df %>% mutate(col1 = gsub("two  (spaces)", "ts", col1))
#>            col1
#> 1     one space
#> 2 two  (spaces)

# Try #2
df %>% mutate(col1 = gsub("two[:space:][:space:](spaces)", "ts", col1))
#>            col1
#> 1     one space
#> 2 two  (spaces)
```

How do I do this properly?

In the first attempt R Studio always changes my two spaces into one tab basically. I'm not sure if that's the issue. My second attempt feels like it should work. Unfortunately, it appears R does not care for my feelings.

Comment: `df %>% mutate(col1 = gsub("two  (spaces)", "ts", col1, fixed = TRUE))` in case anybody sees this in the future.

Comment: If you wish to replace any string surrounded by double quotes that contains a left parenthesis you could obtain matches of the regex `(?<=")[^("]*\([^"]*(?=\")`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WKAusP/1/)